# Ping Command for python

Tags: python, command, bots, discord, ping

Hello I am making a discord bot with Python but I am not getting to how to add ping in bot...like how much ping does Bor have .I have searched on ggl but it is now working if you know please let me know

Comment: what means not working ? Do you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: show minimal working code

Comment: I am not getting error message but the command is not working...the bot is not responding to the command

Comment: if you already tried to add ping then you should show minimal working code which we could run and see problem. Asking `how to add ping to bot` is too broad question and it needs more details - like minimal working code.

Answer (score 2):

For python3 use module [ping3](https://github.com/kyan001/ping3): (pip install ping3, needs root privileges).

```
from ping3 import ping, verbose_ping
ping('google.com')  # Returns delay in seconds. 0.0010232925415039062
```

Answer (score 1):

If your running environment is not windows, you can do this.
You just have to call a system command and check the return code.
If you want to improve this example, you can test the current OS and run the apropriate command.

```
import os
hostname = "yoururl.com"
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:
  print hostname, 'Up'
else:
  print hostname, 'Unreachable'
```

Comment: Ok I will try it